# Android getting data from azure

Tags: android, azure

How can I get data from Azure db so that when I use it in the future it will display the correct content? I tried to use MobileServiceTable<> but it didnt use for(), also I can't convert MobileService<> to List<>. Is there any solution for these problems?

```
MobileServiceClient azur= new MobileServiceClient("https://alcoholo.azure-mobile.net/", "*Cuted*", context);

MobileServiceTable<Events> dupaka =  azur.getTable(Events.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a ready code for use :)

```
public static ArrayList<Events> list = new ArrayList<Events>();

    public static void refreshItemsFromTable() {

        dupaka.execute(new TableQueryCallback<Events>() {

        public void onCompleted(List<Events> result, int count, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {

             //no exception hurray :)
                for (Events item : result) {

                    list.add(item);


                }

            } else {
            //do somthing when are exceptions
            }
        }
    });
 }
```